# Le « heat pipe » reliant le processeur à un échangeur thermique ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, terminologie, informatique

En ce qui a trait à l'aménagement interne d'un [ordinateur portable](https://youtu.be/gpjrbHFv_dA?t=778) :

> We've got a single *heat pipe* running from the CPU over to a small heat
>   exchanger that exhausts here at the back of the unit.

J'aimerais traduire le terme *heat pipe* et pouvoir l'employer dans ce genre de phrase. Il n'y a pas de [*fluide caloporteur*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26544428) ici, que ce soit de manière plus formelle ou dans le contexte d'un système de [*refroidissement à l'eau*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8409085) ; soit le *pipe* est « plein », ou vide et rempli d'air : peut-on néanmoins parler par extension d'un *caloduc* ou y a-t-il un terme plus courant ou mieux adapté ?

Comment: Je ne suis pas expert mais il me semble qu'on parle bien de caloduc

Comment: S'il n'y a pas de fluide caloporteur, peut-on parler de *heat-pipe* en anglais ? J'ai l'impression qu'il s'agit plus d'un radiateur que d'un *caloduc*.

Comment: Les deux mais souvent le système complet : aqueduc, oléoduc. Pour ce qui est du dispositif, je dirais *diffuseur thermique* qui ne présume pas l'existence d'un circuit fermé.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Caloduc*** est construit à l'image d'**aqueduc** (*aquae ductus*: qui conduit l'eau), **oléoduc** (idem pour « l'*huile* de pierre », c'est à dire le pétrole, oléoduc a été crée pour supplanter le *pipe-line* anglais), **gazoduc** (conduit le gaz) et même **viaduc** (« conduit » une voie de part et d'autre d'une zone moins élevée).

Un ***caloduc*** conduit donc la chaleur d'un point à un autre, et la description donnée du dispositif correspond techniquement bien à cet usage.

Cependant, un ***caloduc*** semble toujours décrire en français un dispositif permettant un transfert thermique entre deux zones présentant un écart de température **à l'aide un fluide confiné passant alternativement d'une phase gazeuse à une phase liquide**.

Utiliser ***caloduc*** sans autre forme d'explication pourrait donc être considéré comme un abus, voire une tromperie vue la différence de rendement entre les deux approches mais *JNSPUJ*<sup>1</sup>. Rien n'interdit néanmoins de présenter l'objet en question comme un ***caloduc passif sans changement de phase*** en précisant qu'il s'appuie sur la conductibilité thermique du métal utilisé.

On peut aussi éviter ***caloduc*** et parler de ***diffuseur/transmetteur/propagateur*** thermique métallique.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[IANAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL) ;-)</sub>

Comment: Je dirais: Le *D, T ou P* facilite l'évacuation de la chaleur du processeur vers l'échangeur thermique.

Comment: Bonne nuance. Que penses-tu des termes _conduit_ ou _élément_, thermique ? Ou tu préfères _transmetteur/propagateur_ pour ces fonctions ou s'agit-il de deux manières de décrire la même chose ? Bien le morceau de métal il va toujours diffuser techniquement mais sa fonction c'est vraiment l'échange avec l'autre bout où la chaleur est vraiment diffusée, soit disant.

Comment: Bof, réf: JNSPUJ bien comme tu le sais c'est davantage la conception de l'appareil, comme l'ordi portable ici, qu'un truc qu'on achète comme ça au détail. De toutes façons on pourrait dire « « qui a la fonction d'un caloduc », voire _-caloduc_ etc.

Comment: Oui, *conduit thermique* pourrait aller, même si c'est aujourd'hui essentiellement utilisé pour des tuyaux.